# Calculate $\cos^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{16\pi}{7}\right)$ without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

> Calculate
>   $$\cos^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{16\pi}{7}\right)$$

[original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQFmv.png)

I figured out the reference angle of $2\pi/7$. However, how can you evaluate $2\pi/7$ to be $0$, without memorizing the angle's answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$.

Using this you get $\cos^{-1} (\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{16\pi}{7}))$. Then you can finish it from here (but keep in mind the domain of $\cos^{-1}(x)$)

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\sin\dfrac{16\pi}7=\sin\dfrac{2\pi}7=\cos(\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac{2\pi}7)=\cos\dfrac{\pi(7-4)}{14}$$

Now $\cos^{-1}f(x)=2n\pi\pm\dfrac{3\pi}{14}$ where $n$ is an integer such that $0\le\cos ^{-1}f(x)\le\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\cos^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}x=\frac\pi2 $,

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{16\pi}{7}\right)
=\frac\pi2 - \sin^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{16\pi}{7}\right)
=\frac\pi2 - \sin^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)
=\frac\pi2-\frac{2\pi}{7}=\frac{3\pi}{14} $$